# Combining two SVGs based on edges or points

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, html5-canvas

I have 2 SVG images and want to combine them. Like, I have a dress and a sleeve. I want to fit the sleeve exactly on to the edge with the edge or the ends where it will fit.
**For clarity, I am adding a fiddle at the end of the post**
What is the best way for these 2 elements to place? If I try to use view box positioning, I have to make sure each and every SVG combination is placed before hand to get the right numbers, which is cumbersome.

Is there any programmatic way in javascript to combine them by picking paths and fit like a puzzle?

Comment: The example elements in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sob871zr/1/

Comment: There isn't a way I'm aware of, nothing simple anyway. Your best bet is to just align all your SVGs (or store an offset with each SVG). I wouldn't recommend playing with viewboxes to align them, but rather put the whole svg in a <g transform="translate()"> group.

Comment: Thanks @Eric. If you have time, can you provide sample in the same fiddle or its fork and post it as an answer? That would be very helpful.